# Line too long in PGI 16.9. How to solve?

Tags: openacc, pgi-accelerator

USe the following dummy code to replicate the issue.

```
program pp
  implicit none
  real*8,dimension(45) :: refPoints
  refPoints(:) = (/ -1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 , -1.0 , -1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 , -1.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0 , -1.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0 , -1.0 , -1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 , -1.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0 ,-1.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 1.0, 1.0, 2.0 , 3.0, 34.0, 35.0, 25.0, 1.0, 50.0, 5.0, 55.0 , 1.0 , 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0/)

end program pp
```

PGF90-S-0285-Source line too long (pp.f90: 6)
PGF90-S-0023-Syntax error - unbalanced parentheses (pp.f90: 6)
  0 inform,   0 warnings,   2 severes, 0 fatal for pp

Comment: what about showing the code?

Comment: refPoints(1,:) = (/ -1.0_rp,  1.0_rp,  1.0_rp, -1.0_rp,  -1.0_rp,  1.0_rp, 1.0_rp, -1.0_rp,    0.0_rp,  1.0_rp,  0.0_rp, -1.0_rp,   0.0_rp, 1.0_rp, 0.0\
_rp, -1.0_rp,  -1.0_rp,  1.0_rp, 1.0_rp, -1.0_rp,   0.0_rp, 1.0_rp, 0.0_rp, -1.0_rp,  0.0_rp, 0.0_rp, 0.0_rp  /)

Comment: Thats the line. works fine with all fortran compilers except PGI. For PGI i need to add & symbol for continuation. I have so many of them in the whole code.

Comment: Put the code in the question, this is unreadable in comment. And please add the compiler command line you use.

Comment: I have added a dummy code compile using pgfortran.

Comment: Did you try with `-Mextend` command line option?

Comment: Yes -Mextend does not work.

Comment: -Mextend is for extending fixed format's 72 column limit to 132 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

132 columns is limit the F90 standard and going beyond this limit is undefined behavior. While a pain, you'll be better off in the long run by getting your code into compliance by adding continuations.